# Scratch files in /tmp getting mysteriously deleted

Tags: linux, fedora, io, tmp

I have certain files in a `/tmp` subdirectory that a script I wrote uses for scratch. The opens and closes these file perfectly fine for a few hours. Then, out of nowhere, the files are no longer found.

I looked in `/var/log/messages` and do not see anything that raises any flags around the time that the files disappeared.

Does anyone have any clue as to how I could troubleshoot this?

And yes, I know `/tmp` isn't the ideal location for files I care about but I still would like to know what causes this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stock F14 only deletes `/tmp` files once a day and only if they are more than 10days old via `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`.

You could use the auditing subsystem. Suppose the files are in the dir `/tmp/help`. In `/etc/audit/audit.rules` add

```
-a exit,always -F path=/tmp/help
```

Then restart auditd with `/etc/rc.d/init.d/auditd restart`. Here is what is logged in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` when I execute `rm /tmp/help/heregoes`:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1299113860.183:47): arch=c000003e syscall=263 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=133a0c0 a2=0 a3=1 items=2 ppid=21286 pid=21328 auid=500 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts361 ses=1 comm="rm" exe="/bin/rm" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=CWD msg=audit(1299113860.183:47):  cwd="/root"
type=PATH msg=audit(1299113860.183:47): item=0 name="/tmp/help/" inode=398818 dev=fd:00 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
type=PATH msg=audit(1299113860.183:47): item=1 name="/tmp/help/heregoes" inode=398819 dev=fd:00 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
```

The first (rather long) line shows the executable, pid, and ppid, which may help.

Comment: Note that in empwatch "ten days old" is based on the atime (file access time) by default, but recent (last 3 years) versions of Fedora have a tmpwatch script configured to consider all of atime, mtime, or ctime. If you have your filesystem mounted as noatime, or are putting your files into /tmp with some method (like extracting from an archive) which sets old times, that might explain their "early" disappearance.

Answer (score 2):

`/tmp` is used for temporary file storage. 
Usually it is cleared on boot and/or when it is full and/or on time bases.

I don't know how is it on fedora, but some other unix systems use `/etc/init.d/bootclean.sh` or cronjobs.
`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem if there is more than 1 instance of your script running at the same time?

If there is, try using $$ (which translates to the PID of the process running the script) in the filename. Something like

```
some_command > /tmp/output.$$
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing inotify-tools and then using inotifywait you should be able to see exactly when the file is touched. Using a combination of inotifywait and lsof you should be able to see what process is touching /tmp/

SSH relies upon files in /tmp/ that exist for longer than hours, are other processes being affected by this problem as well?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution the tmp files are possibly being wiped because they have been untouched for an amount of time.

Look for a cronjob named "tmpwatch", probably in /etc/cron.daily

It should definitely be more than "a few hours", the default is between 30 and 60 days.

Comment: Another common one is tmpreaper